# multi-tenant-schemas:dynamic api routing using django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, multi-tenant

I am newbie to Multi-Tenant architecture, developing SaaS product using [django-tenant-schema](http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

my requirement was something like clients would register for product. For every registered client, I was creating new schema by following single database and isolated schemas approach. Whenever client requested from a browser I was able to identify them by using subdomain  and giving privilege to acces their specfic schema. While I was starting coding lot of questions were popup in my head. I am really sorry for asking here but stackoverflow is only my last hope. Database was like below

### Database

- Public_Schema

  - auth_user
  - Clients_List_Table
- ClientA_Schema

  - auth_user
  - ClientA_User_List
- ClientB_Schema

  - auth_user
  - ClientB_User_List

Q1.What kind of admin actions we can perform on every client?

I have rest api for example  **http://client.example.com/api/user_list/** here client maybe ClientA or ClientB

Q2. How can we implement api routing which gets client name dynamically when user requested at browser which let us to use corresponding schema to display current client's user_list.

Any reply can be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I followed [`django-tenants`](https://github.com/tomturner/django-tenants) ,and their team implemented almost everything  required for django multi-tenant SaaS(Software As a Service) application. So I haven't done much work beyond understanding architecture; I just want to answer this question.

First start with admin and their privileges; for the above requirement, I have two  admin roles: **tenants_admin**, **tenant_admin**.

Here, **tenants_admin** (who serve the product) are able to manage **tenants**(individual company who buy the product); **tenants_admin** can manipulate data of tenants and they are located at tables in public schema.

Now coming to **tenant_admin**, who has privilege over data of tenant users (let's say employees in single company).

Now clone the project from `django-tenants`, create app particularly for tenants. These tenant schemas are strongly isolated from each other, include both the app name and `rest_framework` to tenant apps.  Afterwards implement REST API as usual; these API will be navigated automatically by using middleware we created for project.

Comment: Hi, I'm also using django-tenants, but with a decoupled front end. Everything works for per-tenant apps, but I struggle to figure out to make an api for registering of tenants. For per-tenant user registration, I extend BaseUserManager from django.contrib.auth.base_user , but django-tenant docs don't have documentation on that.